# I can not import oracle database from another user

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I exported oracle database from user **c##cuongnguyen**. After i exported, i had dump file , So i want to import this file to another user: **mbbank**

So i run this syntax:

**

> imp mbbank/xxxxxx FROMUSER=c##cuongnguyen TOUSER=mbbank
>   file=C:\oracle\export\cuongnguyen-user.DMP;

**

I recieved the response, it's about character.

> Import: Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on Wed Apr 22 19:30:22 2020
>
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release
>   12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
>
> Export file created by EXPORT:V12.02.00 via conventional path
>
> Warning: the objects were exported by C##CUONGNGUYEN, not by you
>
> import done in WE8MSWIN1252 character set and AL16UTF16 NCHAR
>   character set import server uses AL32UTF8 character set (possible
>   charset conversion) IMP-00085: multiple input files specified for
>   unbounded export file IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully

If you have any ideas, please tell me know, Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to run the command inside the directory where the dmp file is located? Or even put the directory path between ''?

```
cd C:\oracle\export
imp mbbank/xxxxxx FROMUSER=c##cuongnguyen TOUSER=mbbank file=cuongnguyen-user.DMP
```

or

```
imp mbbank/xxxxxx FROMUSER=c##cuongnguyen TOUSER=mbbank file='C:\oracle\export\cuongnguyen-user.DMP'
```

Just for your knowledge, oracle has a more improved database export and import tool: `expdp` and `impdp`. And you can do it in your own way:

1. Creating a directory of export inside database:

> ```
> $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus '/ as sysdba'
> SQL> create or replace directory export as 'C:\oracle\export';
> ```

2. Exporting the schema:

> `expdp mbbank/xxxxxx dumpfile=cuongnguyen-user.DMP directory=export schemas=c##cuongnguyen`

3. Finally importing as a new user:

> `impdp mbbank/xxxxxx dumpfile=cuongnguyen-user.DMP directory=export schemas=c##cuongnguyen remap_schema=c##cuongnguyen:mbbank`

Comment: Hi @Henique, 
Thank you a lot for your helping. 

Your method really work, Thank you so much,  expdp and impdp are bettter